# Overloading ostream friend operator with shared_ptr vector

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr, friend

I am trying to overload the ostream operator as a friend in a class to build components of a circuit, however it keeps returning the address.

In a series-circuit class in the file "Circuit_classes.h":

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, series_circuit const& myCircuit);
```

In the file "Circuit_classes.cpp":

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, series_circuit const& myCircuit){
    os << "Output: " << myCircuit.frequency << endl;
    return os;
}
```

where `frequency` is defined in the class header file as 60.

In my main program, "AC Circuits.cpp"

```
vector<shared_ptr<circuit>> circuit_vector;
circuit_vector.push_back(shared_ptr<circuit>(new series_circuit));
cout << circuit_vector[0] << endl;
```

Output in the command line when the program is run:

```
0325E180
```

Comment: What is `circuit_vector[0]`? What argument does you `operator<<` function take? Are the two types the same?

Comment: I have accepted the answer by DeiDei, but for reference:
circuit_vector[0] is the series_circuit class added by .push_back, it is a derived class from a base circuit class.
The operator << function takes the arguments of os and the series_circuit class.

Comment: How `series_circuit` related to `circuit` ?

Comment: `series_circuit` is a derived class of the base class  `circuit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << circuit_vector[0] << endl;
```

`circuit_vector[0]` yields a `std::shared_ptr` which is what is being printed.

You must dereference it to get to the object itself.

```
cout << *circuit_vector[0] << endl;
```